# datatype for filename OR http-url

Tags: c#, uri

I would like to be able to pass a filename or a http-url to the constructor of some objects. These objects are able to stream from the url or read the content of file directly. What kind of datatype should I use for and how should I call it. 
Would it be correct to call it `Uri` or is there something more specific?

Comment: How would the objects determine the difference between file and URL? Your question in it's current format is very broad. You can use a `System.String` and depending on what you determine then you can convert to `System.Uri` if needed.

Comment: Well, it is getting passed to some external components. I don't have to determine the difference. I'm just not sure whether there is a good datatype which provides some kind of validation and has a name that tells the user what kind of value is expected.

Comment: Can you show an example of what it would look like as your explanation is not very clear. You can put placeholders to better demonstrate what you mean.

Comment: It is basically a `string`. If it would be a filename, I would call it the parameter itself `filename` type `string` and would call `File.Exists` inside of the `ctor`. If neccessary, I would throw a `FileNotFoundException`. If it would be simple url to a stream on the internet, I would call it `url` of type `string`. I would also some validation. But how should I call a parameter that can be filename and url in once. And is there any datatype that does some kind of validation? I know the `Uri` structure. But I'm not sure whether it is correct to call it an `Uri`.

Comment: You are basically describing a path to a resource so just call it `string path`. as for validation you will have to do that yourself. If it's a valid url then convert it to a url otherwise make your call to `File`